# Failed on fscanf [^,]

Tags: c, scanf

The codes are

```
i=0;
while (fscanf(fp, "%[^,],%[^,],%[^\n]\n", &a,&b,&c) == 3) i++;
```

the file is

```
abc,def,ghi
cdb,adf,wea
adf,adf,wee
```

but the result are

```
a=abc
b=def,ghi
c=cdb
```

what is the problem? thank you.

Comment: How are you declaring a, b, and c?

Comment: char a[256],b[256],c[256];

Comment: What you are specifying an *array* to `scanf`, you should not use `&`. This is not the reason for the problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
while (fscanf(fp, "%[^,],%[^,],%[^\n]\n", a,b,c) == 3) i++;
```

You are declaring a, b, and c to be arrays. What you want is to pass the pointer to the arrays into `fscanf`. You need to either specify the pointer as `a` or as `&a[0]`.

[EDIT]

The following program works for me. Can you try it?

```
#include <stdio.h>
main () {
    char a[32], b[32], c[32];
    int i=0;
    while (fscanf(stdin, "%[^,],%[^,],%[^\n]\n", a, b, c) == 3) {
        i++;
    }
    printf ("%s %s %s\n", a, b, c);
}
```

Comment: Can you post your entire program? In particular, how are you printing out a, b, and c?